# Plot graph in R and don't want NA to show

Tags: r, ggplot2, na

I want to plot a grouped graph in ggplot in R but don't want the NA to show.

I have the following code:

```
lusl %>%
  ggplot(aes(wave, generalhealth)) + geom_point(alpha = .005) +
  stat_summary(aes(color = harassment_fct, group = harassment_fct),
                fun.y = mean, geom = "line", lwd = 1.5) +
  labs(x = "Wave", y = "GHQ-12 Value", color = "Experience of Racial Harassment")
```

And I get the following graph:

[image]

How do I get rid of the NA?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a reproducible example and understanding the structure of your database, a simple option is to use `drop_na()` to remove any row containing `NA` values.

```r
lusl %>% 
  drop_na() %>%
  ggplot(aes(wave, generalhealth)) + geom_point(alpha = .005) # etc.
```

If you want a more precise removal of the `NA` values, only in `harassment_fct` (used for `color`), then filter these out:

```r
lusl %>% 
  filter(!is.na(harassment_fct)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(wave, generalhealth)) + geom_point(alpha = .005) # etc.
```